# Document library setup for Workspace synchronization on views

Tags: workspace

I am looking into having a single document library in SharePoint 2010 with the possibility to have Sharepoint 2010 Workspace synchronize with separate filtered views of that list.
For example, if I would have a column called "Color", I would like one client to synchronize with the green documents, another one just the red documents, and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible currently.  SP Workspace will sync a whole library.  I have read somewhere that you can set it up to sync just a folder and it's subfolders but I haven't tried it.

Comment: As user of the client you can do it folder by folder. Means you have the choice to decide to download only specific folders or just headers. But if you have right to get this folder, you can do so. Later or now. Workspace 2010 is not a tool to enjoy SharePoint.